# Valid-url heroku deployment issue on push

Tags: heroku, node-modules, package.json, heroku-cli

I'm getting the error valid-url not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-buildpacks when I try to push code to heroku using the CLI or through GitHub.

I've tried everything I could find on the internet including stack exchange to solve this problem, so I would really appreciate some help here.

I've done everything in the following link but am still experiencing the same issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/m0vs4l/deploy_from_github_to_heroku_what_does_validurl/

My package.json is as follows

```
    {
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "prodd": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroku/buildpack-registry": "^1.0.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.874.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^1.8.2",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.0.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.6",
    "google-auth-library": "^7.0.4",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "heroku": "^7.60.2",
    "html-to-text": "^7.0.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mjml": "^4.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "redis": "^3.1.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "select": "^1.1.2",
    "sharp": "^0.28.3",
    "twilio": "^3.59.0",
    "util": "^0.12.3",
    "validator": "^13.5.2",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  }
}
```

My global installations are as follows.
[image: globals]

I would really appreciate some help on this! It's pushing to GitHub and working locally fine so it just seems to be something with the web pack.

I've deployed this same app and others to heroku multiple times in the past but am on a new computer now. Perhaps this has something to do with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't specified the npm version in my `package.json` in the engines section. I specified it to the same npm version I was running locally and it all worked.